# Scroll x in responsive div container

Tags: html, responsive-design, overflow

I don't know why but I have a section tag that is responsive it adjusts to the screen size in width. The problem is that I placed overflow auto if the content exceeds but instead of showing scrollbar it grows.

```js
<div className="w-full">
      <section className="inline-flex w-full flex-col gap-2
      overflow-x-auto border max-w-full">
        <div className="w-[2000px] h-11 inline-flex bg-black">

          </div>
        
      
      </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, but you can just change `max-w-full` to `max-w-vw`, but I think it is more predictive to use `w-vw` (insted of `w-full`) in the parent div to delimit the content inside, like in this section.